# Use value of one procedure in another procedure

Tags: mysql

I am calling one procedure from another

```
CREATE PROCEDURE choice_select(IN choice_value BIGINT)
BEGIN

    DECLARE AA varchar(100);
    CALL TEST(choice_value,AA);

    SELECT  description
    FROM    academic
    where   {select a};

END
```

`TEST` is my another procedure and I want to pass the value returned from `TEST` procedure; in the `WHERE` clause, `wherea` is an output variable.

Comment: Why don't you use scalar function instead of calling another SP if your TEST return to single value?

Comment: In the select statement, which field are you comparing the returned value with?

Comment: In the second procedure i am returning a list of values and i am comparing with academic_id

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:

Use FIND_IN_SET function to filter records -

BEGIN
  SET @aa = NULL;
  CALL test(@aa); -- test should return a string like this - '1,2,3,4,5'
  SELECT description FROM academic WHERE FIND_IN_SET(academic_id, @aa);
END

Plan B:

Populate a (temporary) table in the `test` procedure, then join this table with `academic` table.